# how to redirect user to login page after sign out with jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I'm using jetpack compose in my project. My app contains multiple screens and nested navigation.
So I have this in my MainActivity:

```
   val startDestination = if (setting.isUserLoggedIn)
            HomeNavGraph.HomeRoute.route
        else
            AuthenticationNavGraph.AuthenticationRoute.route

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            DoneTheme {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = startDestination
                ) {
                    authentication(navController = navController)
                    home()
                }
            }
        }
```

This code decides that, based on whether the user has already logged in, navigate the user to the authentication screen or home screen. The home navigation is like this:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.home() {
    navigation(
        startDestination = HomeNavGraph.HomeScreen.route,
        route = HomeNavGraph.HomeRoute.route
    ) {
        composable(route = HomeNavGraph.HomeScreen.route)
        {
            HomeRouteScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

The `HomeRouteScreen()` per se, has bottom navigation and its navHost.
Now I want to navigate the user from the profile screen in `HomeRouteScreen()` to the Authentication screen that its composable is defined in the MainActivity nav graph.

my problem is:

If I call `navcontroller.navigate(AuthenticationNavGraph.AuthenticationScreen.route)`, I get the error that the destination is not explicitly in the current nav graph. On the other hand, if I use the `navController` which exists in Main Activity, in `HomeRouteScreen` I get the error that  `ViewModelStore should be set before setGraph call`. So How should I handle this issue?

Comment: Eventually I managed to workaround this problem with this article: [link](https://paulallies.medium.com/login-logout-flow-android-jetpack-compose-and-compositionlocal-d2d1784c0d15). They are using state in whole app and switch graphs based on this state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are pressing a Sign Out Button inside the ProfileScreen:

```
onClick = {
    viewModel.logOut().also {
        navHostController.navigate(Screens.SignInScreen.route) {
            popUpTo(Screens.HomeScreen.route) {
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
     }
},
```

Remember that HomeScreen is my **current first destination** in the backstack.